# Using Sed Awk Bash to populate variable in search

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed, cut

I have several xml files that contain multiple sections.
One of the sections in these files is "PublishMgr". Below this section
there are two lines containing server names and port. I need to 
extracts the servers and ports  and place them into variables
and run query against them. I really don't know
any easy way to do this. I was thinking using awk and sed, but 
my knowledge of these are limited. Can you assist pls?
I have gotten as far as getting the lines printed. I could use awk -F   to get host name and port number for the first entry , but not sure how to do it for second line?  I like to do it in one sweep if possible and not do this query twice? Can this be done?

Please note the I want to assign the output to 4 distinct variable !

My Code

```
cat filename | grep -A6 PublishMgr | grep "Address\|BacKMeUp"
```

XML-FILE/TXT Only portion of the file

```
<<!--==========================================-->
<!--   PublishMgr                          -->
<!--==========================================-->

<goandpublishme>

<ClassPub name="buylimit" pers="Y">
<prime>host9:1000</prime>
<backup>host145:9999</backup>
</ClassPub>
```

Current Output

```
   <prime>host9:1000</prime>
   <backup>host145:9999</backup>
```

Desired Output  like to assign the results to variable
Please note the I want to assign the output to 4 "distinct" variables.
So I can use them for further inquiry like a simple example will be 
cd abc/$srv1;grep ports $srv1.log. In short I need to have $srv1 $srv2 $port1 $port2

```
srv1=host9    
port1=1000    
srv1=host145
port2=9999
```

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Post an example with valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is directly catering to your desired output, and is based on the fact that you say your knowledge of sed and awk is limited.

If this is your current output

```
   <prime>host9:1000</prime>
   <backup>host145:9999</backup>
```

Then you could get the desired output by adding a sed command with multiple expressions, and iterating through the list of line match terms:

```
| sed -E -e "s/(^\s*)(<.[^>]*>)/srv$i=/g" -e "s/(<.[^>]*>)//g" -e "s/(:)/\nport$i=/g"
```

A breakdown of this is as follows:

**`-e "s/(^\s*)(<.[^>]*>)/srv$i=/g"`**

- `(^\s*)` - Start of line followed by unlimited whitespaces
- `(<.[^>]*>)`  - these `<>` and anything in-between
- `/srv$i=/g` - Replace with srv followed by increment number.

**`-e "s/(<.[^>]*>)//g"`** Remove leading spaces

**`-e "s/(:)/\nport=/g"`** Replaces `:` with `\n` (new line) and `port=`

### Take this test file **`input.txt`**, which contains:

```
<<!--==========================================-->
<!--   PublishMgr                          -->
<!--==========================================-->

<goandpublishme>

<ClassPub name="buylimit" pers="Y">
<prime>host9:1000</prime>
<backup>host145:9999</backup>
</ClassPub>
```

### Your line list is: `prime backup`

**Iterate through a list of line matches**

```
i=1 ; for predicate in prime backup ; do grep -P "$predicate" <input.txt | sed -E -e "s/(^\s*)(<.[^>]*>)/srv$i=/g" -e "s/(<.[^>]*>)//g" -e "s/(:)/\nport$i=/g" ; (( i++ )) ; done
```

**Results:**

```
srv1=host9
port1=1000
srv2=host145
port2=9999
```

### To Actually Assign (Not Print):

```
OLDIFS="$IFS" ; IFS=$'\n' ; for line in "$(i=1 ; for predicate in prime backup ; do grep -P "$predicate" <input.txt | sed -E -e "s/(^\s*)(<.[^>]*>)/srv$i=/g" -e "s/(<.[^>]*>)//g" -e "s/(:)/\nport$i=/g" ; (( i++ )) ; done)" ; do eval "$line" ; done ; IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Breakdown:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS="$IFS"                                  #Save current IFS just for good measure
IFS=$'\n'                                      #Set IFS to new-line
for line in "$(i=1
    for predicate in prime backup
        do grep -P "$predicate" <input.txt \
        | sed -E -e "s/(^\s*)(<.[^>]*>)/srv$i=/g"\
             -e "s/(<.[^>]*>)//g" \
             -e "s/(:)/\nport$i=/g"
             (( i++ ))
        done)"                                #The original script broken into lines
        do 
            eval "$line"                      #Actually assign the variables
        done
IFS="$OLDIFS"                                 #Restore IFS

echo "\$srv1 is: $srv1"                       #Print values of assigned variables
echo "\$srv2 is: $srv2"
echo "\$port1 is: $port1"
echo "\$port2 is: $port2"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the elaborate description. Your sed comments work but I need to assign the output to 4 distinct variables. I am sorry if I was not clear in the description of the problem.  I have updated it.  I need to use these variable to do further inquiries. Thanks

Comment: @theuniverseisflat Have a look at my edit, now that your requirements are clearer

Comment: @theuniverseisflat given that your input.txt looks the same as what is demonstrated, use this line: `i=1 ; for predicate in prime backup ; do grep -P "$predicate" <input.txt | sed -E -e "s/(^\s*)(<.[^>]*>)/srv$i=/g" -e "s/(<.[^>]*>)//g" -e "s/(:)/\nport$i=/g" ; (( i++ )) ; done`

Comment: the problem is that I am unable to assign these outputs to variables. I can now get the output using sed or awk command but the VAR assignment does not work. Pls see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545583/unable-to-assign-output-of-sed-or-awk-command-to-variables-can-only-print-them

Comment: @theuniverseisflat see update down the bottom.  Done.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat the one liner can be executed in a shell session and set the variables for the current session, the breakdown version (which is the same) illustrates use within a script.  In this case, I've just echo'd the variables, but you could do whatever you need to with them.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not use line-oriented tools like `sed` and `awk` to process XML data. You should use an XML-aware tool instead. Assuming that your document is indeed valid XML, you could use `xmlstarlet` to extract the information:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'concat("srv1=", substring-before(//ClassPub/prime, ":"))' -nl \
    -t -v 'concat("port1=", substring-after(//ClassPub/prime, ":"))' -nl publish.xml
```

Just replace `prime` with `backup` and adjust the strings accordingly. I suspect you might have meant `srv2`.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try that. Yes it is xml formatted file/ I let you kow

Comment: I need to produce 4 distinct variables so I can use later in the script.

Comment: srv1="host9"
port1="1000"
srv2=host145
port2=9999