# Unable to assign output of sed or awk command to variables? Can only print them

Tags: bash, awk, sed, global-variables

I use this command to extract 2 lines from a text file:

```
cat file1 | grep -A7 SECTIONA  | grep -E 'Address|BackupAddress'
```

This produces the two lines below:

```
Address host1  port_1  Address
BackupAddress host2 port_2  BackupAddress
```

I need to assign (not print) the host and port columns to distinct global variables to use later in the script.

```
hosta="host1"
porta="port_1"
hostb="host2"
portb="port_2"
```

A member suggested I use this and I get the desired output, however I cannot use the variables in the current shell? When I try to print or use them they come out blank. I also have an awk solution to get the desired output, but both sed and awk commands just print the above and do not create the variables?

```
sed -n 's/^Address *\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\).*/hosta="\1"\nporta="\2"/p;
s/^BackupAddress *\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\).*/hostb="\1"\nportb="\2"/p' file1
```

I can get around all this by breaking the sed and awk command into 4 sections and run the same query 4 times but there must be a better way. for example I can do:

```
hosta=`cat file | sed/or/awk command` 
porta=`cat file | sed/or/awk command` 
hostb=`cat file | sed/or/awk command` 
portb=`cat file | sed/or/awk command`
```

When I do the query using awk or sed command to get the desired output they get assigned to variables and I can print or use the variables as I like; but I do not want to run the query 4 times.

Can anyone help please

Comment: yes Inian 2 lines and 4 variables in this case

Comment: My question was, if this could be the case _all_ the time? just two lines (or) can the number vary and _exactly_ 4 variables? A more generic solution can be approached that way

Comment: Yes this is the case all the time. The host address and port  lines are generic across all the files we use. So there are two lines that I grep out of the files and they will always contain 4 variables. Hope this answers ur question

Comment: @theuniverseisflat Ok, given your more detailed criteria, I've provided an answer that might help.  You need to be more specific if it's insufficient as a number of answers so far have only resulted in you elaborating further.

Answer (score 1):

Checking that input doesn't contain invalid character, the output can be sourced same as "eval"ed. in that case negative character set `[^ ]` should be replaced by a positive character set to match expected characters

```
output=$(sed ...)
eval "$output"
```

or

```
eval "$(sed ...)"
```

or

```
source <(sed ...)
```

Comment: Sorry I dio not understand ur post.

Answer (score 0):

> this is the case **all the time**. The host address and port lines are
>   generic across all the files... 
> ...So there are **two lines** that I
>   grep out of the files and they **will always contain 4 variables**.

Given the specificity of the application, you could:

- Scan the file **once**
- Save the results into a variable
- Parse only the variable to assign the host and port variables

Given the input file **input.txt**, which contains:

```
Address host1  port_1  Address
BackupAddress host2 port_2  BackupAddress
```

You could use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

lines="$(grep -P "Address|BackupAddress" <input.txt)"             #Get the two lines needed

hosta="$(awk '/^Address/ { print $2 }' <<<"${lines[@]}")"         #Assign $hosta
porta="$(awk '/^Address/ { print $3 }' <<<"${lines[@]}")"         #Assign $porta
hostb="$(awk '/^BackupAddress/ { print $2 }' <<<"${lines[@]}")"   #Assign $hostb
portb="$(awk '/^BackupAddress/ { print $3 }' <<<"${lines[@]}")"   #Assign $portb

#Use the results how you like.  Here we just echo them back:

echo "$hosta"
echo "$porta"
echo "$hostb"
echo "$portb"
```